# Generate a temporary duplicate page on ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, temporary-files

I was unable to find this searching online, I could only find creating a temporary download link. I want to basically create a new temporary webpage/url that is a duplicate of an existing page. What is the best way to go about doing that?

Let's say I have Default.aspx, and the content of the page is just something like (just an example, will obviously be much more content/scripts)

```
    <div class="example">
    Test
    </div>
```

And then a user clicks Button1, then it should generate a duplicate of that page on a different URL and it should be temporary, so delete itself in like 2 to 3 hours?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can write the stream to a temp file with code similar to:

```
string sourceFileUrl="<MY URL>/SourcePage.aspx";

Stream responseStream = WebRequest.Create(sourceFileUrl).GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    byte[] htmlBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
    string filename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Temp\";
    fileName += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +Path.GetExtension(sourceFileUrl);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, htmlBytes );
}
```